# How to read a hex ".dat" file with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have a ".dat" file that I believe is storing some information that I need to access for a Python 3 program I am writing.

I am not familiar with ".dat" files but when I open the file with a text editor it appears to be hex.. here is a small sample from the file:

```
0000 0000 0000 1a74 0000 0001 5643 5000
0000 0003 3132 3031 3936 7241 2031 3331
3344 5820 4c30 3700 0000 0002 5669 7274
7561 6c20 4350 0000 0000 0008 0000 0000
0000 000e 0000 0000 0000 000f 0000 0000
0000 000d 0000 0002 0000 000c 0000 0000
0000 0009 0000 0000 0000 0023 0000 0000
0000 0032 0000 0002 0000 0037 3632 3953
3039 2d30 3430 3900 0000 0039 0000 0028
0000 0004 0000 ffff 0000 0005 0000 0400
0000 0006 0000 0400 0000 0033 0000 0001
0000 0034 0000 0001 0000 0035 0000 0001
0000 0091 0000 0000 0000 00c8 0000 4b00
0000 00c9 0000 0000 0000 00fa 09f3 978c
0000 00fb a1d3 5754 0000 00fc ffbf cc71
0000 00fd 2566 0397 0000 00fe b871 c3ae
0000 0096 0000 0041 3278 3220 302e 3570
4620 5647 3200 0000 0000 003f 2000 0000
0000 0013 ffff ffff 0000 0042 0000 0000
0000 0048 0000 0000 0000 004f 0000 0001
0000 0046 0000 ea60 0000 0047 0000 ea60
```

Can I read this into python 3 and convert it to something human readable to find the setting I need?

Comment: This is the most human-readable you can get, unless it is encoding something in a non-trivial format. How can you "believe it has some information your program need to access", if you don't know what it is?

Comment: This appears to be a MacBinary 2 header file, according to trid.

Comment: If you are trying to decode MacBinary II, [this specification](http://hackipedia.org/File%20formats/Containers/MacBinary%20(archive)/MacBinary%20II%20file%20format.html) and Python's [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) are your friends. If you give us more details, we might help you better.